# How to show a field as Currency but with the data type being Text - Access 2013

Tags: vba, ms-access

In my Access iv'e got a form in which I want to display several table-bound (record source) fields  as Currency, with their table datatype being Text.

I can't seems to get this done. What I tried so far to achieve this:

- Use a `Format` in the controlsource of the field so (in the controlsource of the field): `=Format(MyTextNumber; "Currency")` - Results in #Type error (Circular reference)
- Use `CCur` in the controlsource of the field: `=CCur(MyTextNumber)` - This returns all 0.00 amounts (with the currency symbol though) and also a Circular reference Error in the design.
- Instead of using the `table` as Recordsource in the form I used a query as Recordsource in which I created another field based on the Field I try to change: `SELECT *, Format(MyTextNumber, "Currency") as MyTextNumberWithFormat FROM SomeTable` I then used the `MyTextNumberWithFormat` as controlsource, this returns good values but I can't edit these values directly because it is based on an expression.
- Also tried to create a hidden field with the controlsource and create an 'empty controlsource field' that uses the hidden field as its value and then write my own `UPDATE` statement when the field is being changed (but couldn't get this to work either).

Any other suggestions?

**Additional information:**

I also tried to set the Format/Notation on Currency/Euro in the Formatting tab of the field but this also doesn't have any effect, though what is kinda interesting is the fact that when I use `=Sum(MyField)` as Recordsource, then the Format/Notation Currency DOES work.

Comment: Yes I did. Currency on the Format property and the control source to only the table field (sorry by the way for using recordsource where it should be Controlsource, I couldnt come up with the word when writing the post - adjusted recordsource to controlsource in the main post where needed)

Comment: Text is text and numbers are numbers. Formatting `Sum()` works, because it results in a number. The only thing that `Format: Currency` will do for a text column is right-align the field. The best way would be to fix your data type. If the field holds a currency value, why not change it to Currency? All `=...` expressions will always be read-only.

Comment: Ah good to know about the =expression always turns it into read-only! Sadly I can't change the format to currency or any number for that matter.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT Table1.Test, Format([test],"Currency") AS Expr1
FROM Table1;
```

this worked for me, I've entries of "£123.45" and "123.45" and were presented in currency.  You had ; in your's

Comment: As said, I already tested this (and not with the ; but with the , as well) see point 3 it's there with the comma as well. And although it show's the value correct in the Currency format, I can not EDIT the record then because the value is `based on an expression`. What I want is to show the good formatting (currency) but also being able to change the Value.

Comment: Could you do a one time pass adding the currency format to the existing text in the table, then have a before update code on the textbox adding it if it's not there? if mid(textbox1.value,1,1)<>"£" then....

Comment: Thanks for the Input Nathan! Not entirely sure what you mean with the Before_Update statement. Could you give some code example. Tried to do it myself with doing the Format on the textbox value (on the Form_beforeUpdate event) if it has not the Currency symbol (used the mid code you provided) but this didn't seem to work. 
Private Sub Form_BeforeUpdate(Cancel As Integer)
`If Mid(Me.MyTextBox.Value, 1, 1) <> "€" Then
    Me.CorEenheidPrijs.Value = Format(Me.MyTextBox.Value, "Currency")
End If
End Sub`

Answer (score 0):

> Results in #Type error (Circular reference)

Then rename your textbox to something else than `MyTextNumber`.